# JPA functionality in a deployed WAR on Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jpa, war

I'm working on a project which aims to allow a user to add some film details to a database and displays the list of existing films. 
I have created a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse using JPA to communicate with a remote database. All of this works fine when I run the project in the Eclipse IDE but when I export it to a WAR and deploy it on a Tomcat server the JPA functionality no longer works. The following error is thrown:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    servlets.AdminMenu.doGet(AdminMenu.java:31)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
    servlets.DBOperator.getFilmList(DBOperator.java:22)
    servlets.AddFilm.doGet(AddFilm.java:28)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    servlets.AdminMenu.doGet(AdminMenu.java:31)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Do I need to package my `persistence.xml` etc. in a certain way before exporting and deploying?

Comment: Is your deployed service running?

Comment: *It doesn't read from the database*: then what does it do instead, if it doesn't throw an exception either?

Comment: Sorry I had left something out. Now it throws the error as per edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most JPA libraries only come native to J2EE containers such as JBOSS, Glassfish, etc...  Tomcat is a Servlet Container not a J2EE container. You would need to include the JPA implementation that you are seeking to use as a dependency and deploy it with your WAR.

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious but how would I do this?

Comment: You would need to find / Google for your favorite JPA Implementation for Tomcat. EclipseLink at is a good one http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EmployeeXML or something like http://tomee.apache.org/index.html   ..

Comment: How do I actually _include the JPA implementation as a dependency_?

Comment: I'm not sure if you use Maven or not, but you'll need to add the jar file of the implementation to your war the same way you would any other library.

Comment: You mean to say that, we need to use a JPA implementation such as Hibernate or EclipseLink if we use Tomcat as our server?

Comment: Hibernate or EclipseLink is a good choice. If you use TomEE or Wildfly one of them is already provided by the server. If you use Tomcat, you have to provide one yourself. Either as part of your war or by extending the Tomcat installation. This has happened already for TomEE.